# On iPad [MFMessageComposeViewCont canSendText] returns YES?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

It's surprising that I can send message on my iPad.
The method `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` returns `YES` even on iPad.
I don't know why. It was OK (the method would return NO) when I tested about 2 month ago.

The iOS version is 5.1 (9B176) and the device is iPad 2 (new Pad has the problem as well).
The xcode version is 4.3.1

Has anybody met the same problem?

---

@jrturton: Yes, you're right. When I turn iMessage off, `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` returns `NO`.
It seems that `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]` can NOT be used to find whether the device could send SMS. So how?

Comment: Just a guess, but if the iPad is configured to send iMessages wouldn't this return YES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the release of iOS 5 and iMessage, and iPad configured to send iMessages, will return `YES` on `[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]`.

This is not a bug/error, it's, as Apple would call it, A Feature! I do understand the confusion though, as the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) for `MFMessageComposeViewController` doesn't mention the possibility of an iPad having activated iMessage.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any method to get whether the device can send SMS? Because my app will need to send SMS (not iMessage), I have to check whether the device can do it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to check specifically for the ability to send SMS. Theoretically, you could check if the device can make calls, because in most cases, a device that can make calls and send messages, is an iPhone. `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://"]]`

Comment: Oh, I can use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"sms://"]] directly. Thank you very much. The question is over.